# can run project on local host because error creating bean with name

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bouncycastle, autowired

I just worked in a new office, and I want to setup all the project of my office to my localhost.

When i want to run the project on my localhoost, I have this error :

> Error creating bean with name 'pageController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.ptdam.ecomm.gateway.service.ServiceSecurity
>   com.ptdam.ecomm.gateway.controller.PageController.serviceSecurity;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

My project was based in Java and using Maven. Can some one help me ? If my information on this question unclear, you can directly ask me on the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can`t find class BouncyCastleProvider. It is in`org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdkXX`Please check dependencies in your`pom.xml`, make sure`org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdkXX` is included in it. For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.45</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have checked, and it's have been included on my pom.xml

`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
   <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>D:\Samuel\Work\essential\bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar</systemPath>
   <version>1.46</version>
  </dependency>`